# Getting error while case_when() applied on empty column in R

Tags: r

I have several dataframes with same column names. I wrote a code to perform some operations on a column based on several conditions. But I got error if all the values of that column is empty.

For an example, if my dataframe is like below, my code works fine.

| unit | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| C | 70 |
| C |  |
| F | 20 |
| K | 130 |

But if my dataframe is like below, my code gives error.

| unit | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| K |  |
| C |  |
| F |  |
| C |  |

My code is,

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(temperature = case_when(
               unit == 'C' ~ temperature, 
               unit == 'F' ~ (temperature - 32)*(5/9),
               unit == 'K' ~ temperature - 273))
```

Could someone help?

Comment: It should be a class issue, i.e. your temperature column consists of empty strings (Character class) and hence you cannot perform mathematical operations on it

Comment: Is the missing value empty string, or is it `NA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force your empty column (it does not matter if it contains empty strings or logical NA's) to a specific data type, i.e. in this case to a numeric class. Then your `case_when()` should work and should return `NA` (`NA_real_`)

```
library(dplyr)    

tibble::tribble(~unit, ~temperature,
                    "K","", 
                    "C","", 
                    "F","", 
                    "C", "") %>% 
      mutate(
        temperature = temperature %>% as.numeric(),
        temperature = case_when(
        unit == 'C' ~ temperature, 
        unit == 'F' ~ (temperature - 32)*(5/9),
        unit == 'K' ~ temperature - 273))
```

Comment: It works. As you mentioned it was due to class issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~unit, ~temperature,
  "K", NA,
  "C", NA,
  "F", NA,
  "C", NA
)

data %>%
  mutate(
    temperature = as.numeric(temperature),
    temperature = case_when(
      unit == "C" ~ temperature,
      unit == "F" ~ (temperature - 32) * (5 / 9),
      unit == "K" ~ temperature - 273
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   unit  temperature
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 K              NA
#> 2 C              NA
#> 3 F              NA
#> 4 C              NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It works. I couldn't accept it as accepted answer as I have done it already. But upvoted. Thank you.

Comment: it's fine. @Julian was 10 seconds faster